# caret saving minimum size model

Tags: r, r-caret

In caret how to save minimum size model. In this example the `gbmFit1` contains `gbmFit1$trainingData`. Saving `gbmFit1` saves all such variables. As my training data is big, I want to get rid off all such extra variables and want to save the model with minimum size.

```
  library(mlbench)
  library(caret)
  data(Sonar)
  x <- Sonar[, colnames(Sonar)!="Class"]
  y <- Sonar$Class
  gbmFit1 <- train(x,y, method = "gbm", verbose = FALSE)
  predict(gbmFit1, x[1:10, ]) #predict for 10 samples
  ##[1] R R R R R R R R R R
  ##Levels: M R
  dim(gbmFit1$trainingData) 
  #[1] 208  61
```

Using only `predict(gbmFit1$finalModel, x[1:10, ])` gives error:

```
predict(gbmFit1$finalModel, x[1:10, ])
##Error in paste("Using", n.trees, "trees...\n") : 
##argument "n.trees" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
  data(Sonar)
  x <- Sonar[, colnames(Sonar)!="Class"]
  y <- Sonar$Class
tc1 <- trainControl(returnData = F)  # tells caret not to save training data.
  gbmFit1 <- train(x,y, method = "gbm", verbose = FALSE, trControl = tc1)
  predict(gbmFit1$finalModel, x[1:10, ], gbmFit1$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees) # passes n.trees value to gbm.
```

You might want to read up on the `trainControl` functionality in caret here: https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#control

Comment: Problem with this approach is that in the predict function one have to pass different parameter (such as `n.trees` for `gbm` or `sigma` for `svmRadial`) according to the method used. On the other hand saving full `gbmFit1` do not required any parameter to pass while using `predict`